# Not able to catch a on-click event on an <a> href with Backbone's Events function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, backbone-events, chaplinjs

I am not able to catch `onclick` events in the events object in backbone. I am using the link_to in rails to generate the `<a>` link. Can someone help me out here?

HTML :

```
<div id="flash-messages">
<ul>
<li style="opacity: 1;">
<li style="opacity: 1;">
<li style="opacity: 1;">
<div class="alert alert-info">
<a id="consent-link" href="#">See here for more informationnn.</a>
<a class="controls close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">
<i class="icon-cancel fontLoaded"></i>
</a>
```

JS code:

```
    module.exports = View.extend({
 
   template: template,
   events: {
    'click #btnSubmitModal': 'saveConsent',
    'click #consent-link' : 'openConsent'
   },

   openConsent: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log ("asaasagsgsgs");
    view = new modalView({model: this.model})
   },
```

Comment: You should dump the whole file into a gist or add here. You've left out too much. If I assume you did everything else right this should work but it's not so likely something is off. I'm not familiar with your use of module.exports here (though I usually use require.js) and am confused by the reference to link_to, the HTML should be rendered from a js template and most people wouldn't use a rails helper there.

Comment: Is this the whole view..? Where are you appending the above template into this view..? what is the value of `template`..?

Comment: The template is the whole page template from the handlebars to be loaded in this view.

Comment: @brent The link_to here is just to create the <a> link with an ID and then I am adding event handlers in my backbone view.

Comment: @Ashish : try defining you backbone view el as '#flash-messages'

Comment: wondering whether the answer helped..!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> **template** view.template([data])
>
> While templating for a view isn't a function provided directly by
>   Backbone, it's often a nice convention to define a template function
>   on your views. In this way, when rendering your view, you have
>   convenient access to instance data. For example, using Underscore
>   templates:

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(...)
});
```

---

So template is a custom property that we can use to point to a template function. Defining this isn't enough, you have to create the actual template by passing the data to template function and append the resulting `HTML` to the views element.

Something like:

```
 module.exports = View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  template: Handlebars.compile(template), // where template is the handle bars template
  events: {
   'click #btnSubmitModal': 'saveConsent',
   'click #consent-link' : 'openConsent'
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.append(this.template(data)); //where data is the data you wish to pass to handle bars template function
  },
  openConsent: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log ("asaasagsgsgs");
    view = new modalView({model: this.model})
  }
 });
```

The event handlers are scoped to (delegated to ) the view's element. Once you append the `HTML` to the view's element (as shown in the `render` method of above example) the events will start working.